# Rewrite URL of php page to be png

Tags: php, url-rewriting, png

I am thinking of making a tool for my own development similar to placehold.it.  I would like to have something like this.

```
<img src="url.com/picture.php?id=51"/>
```

to be

```
<img src="url.com/51.png"/>
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Even though I have used Stack Overflow to answer questions and looks stuff up, this is my first time asking a question.  This is a bit crazy.  Apparently it isn't detailed enough. I just thought that less is more sometimes and it seemed to make sense.

Anyway... I am simply wondering if you can make a php page behave like a image.   I would like to be able to pass data to my php page, do stuff with the variables, then return content in the form of an image.  For example:

This

```
<img scr="url.com/picture.php?color=blue"/>
```

Could be seen by the browser as

```
    <img scr="url.com/blue.png"/>
```

My guess is it needs to be done with a rewrite rule. I have done a little work with those in the past for making pretty urls (www.example.com/some/random/url vs example.com/someRandom.php?a=url) but I wasn't sure if changing the type from php to png would work.

Hopefully this will make sense now.

Comment: Four close votes for a question with obvious answer . Sheesh guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using `.htaccess`.Here is the RewriteRule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).png$ /picture.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Thanks.

Comment: If my code work don't forget to mark as correct. Because your opinion will help other to solve their problem. Thank you.